# How can I compile my project with libbmp?

Tags: c, image, image-processing, openmp

I am working on a project and I have include the libbmp library which is available online.
When I try to compile using gcc main.c it throws errors "undefined reference to..."
Do anyone know which instruction do I have to use to compile using the library?

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
gcc main.c -lbmp
```

This `-l` option tells the compiler (linker actually) to link your program with the `bmp` library.